# Post title is not showing

Tags: posts

```
<div class="text_area">
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    the_content();
} // end while
} // end if
?>
      <div class="publish_date">Post Date: <?php the_time('F jS, Y');?> By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?><?php _e( ' Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>· Tags: <a href="#">CSS</a> · <a href="#">Web Design</a> · <a href="#">Full Story</a></div>
    </div>
```

For first post, It shows the title but for second it directly start with content without showing the POST TITLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part

```
<div class="publish_date">Post Date: <?php the_time('F jS, Y');?> By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?><?php _e( ' Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>· Tags: <a href="#">CSS</a> · <a href="#">Web Design</a> · <a href="#">Full Story</a></div>
    </div>
```

should be **inside** the loop (just above or below your call to `the_content();`), not outside

For further info and reading, check out [the loop in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Also, please properly indent your code. Proper indentation makes debugging easier, is easier to read, better supported by code editors and looks neater

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the twenty fourteen contents inside the loop

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
            endif;

            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                    twentyfourteen_posted_on();

                if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
            ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php
                endif;

                edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php the_tags( '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ..I 'll put my code properly from next time. But still post title is missing for second post .

Comment: Just add `the_title();` inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

You would add the code for your date to your content.php file inside the entry-meta div and after the entry title as you can see in this basic example:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <div class="publish_date">Post Date: <?php the_time('F jS, Y');?> By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?><?php _e( ' Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>· Tags: <a href="#">CSS</a> · <a href="#">Web Design</a> · <a href="#">Full Story</a></div>
    </div>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Here's the [position in the Twenty Thirteen themes content.php file](https://github.com/braddalton/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/content.php#L28)